# Width property applied to td

Tags: html, css, html-table

Width property isn't working here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
                td {
    height: 50px;
    width: 25px;
    border: 1px dashed blue
    }

                table {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px
    }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Table cells don't want to become narrow. Why? Also, it seems that there is something wrong with height property too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As HaukurHaf mentioned, the `<td>` are expanding automatically expanding to fill the `<tr>` .

You can force the `<td>`  to accept the specified width and height by changing it's display property to `inline-block`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/g6qzM/)

Answer (score 3):

It's because the table is set at 400px width.  The cells you have will auto expand to fill the width of the table.  Remove the 400px width of the table and your cells should become 25px each.

Comment: Is it imossible to indicate a size to the table and rows at the same time?

Comment: No, but you cannot specify a width for both the table and the cells, unless the widths match.  If you only specify a width for the table, then the cells will automatically get equal widths, which is (tablewidth / cell count).

Answer (score 0):

Your table styles are overriding your td styles.
To see what I mean:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
                td {
    height: 50px;
    width: 25px;
    border: 1px dashed blue
    }

                table {
    border: 1px solid black;
    /*width: 400px;
    height: 400px;*/
    }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

and here's a working [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dj6z3/)